# Compiled PHP 7 missing mysql extension in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have built PHP 7 with a configuration that worked for a previous version of PHP.
Now my WordPress websites get the message:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Other websites using mysqli do work. What am I missing?

I've also included all .so files with mysql in the name:

```
extension=dba.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysqlnd_mysql.so
extension=mysqlnd_mysqli.so
extension=mysqlnd.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_odbc.so
extension=odbc.so
```

Comment: There could well be a deluge of Wordpress users facing similar issues.  Could this question and answer be a generic catch all?

Comment: Great question btw this can help future people who don't realize the extension was removed in PHP 7.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been mentioned elsewhere, the `ext/mysql` functions have been removed. We've been [talking about this for some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

> ext/mysql was built for MySQL 3.23 and only got very few additions since then while mostly keeping compatibility with this old version which makes the code a bit harder to maintain.

If you're hell-bent on putting them back in, you can add them back to PHP 7 by using the [ext/mysql PECL Library](https://pecl.php.net/package/mysql)

It's important to note that [Wordpress 3.9 or later supports mysqli](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/)

> In WordPress 3.9, we added an extra layer to WPDB, causing it to switch to using the mysqli PHP library, when using PHP 5.5 or higher.

Comment: I found this post helpful for adding the mysql extension back to PHP 7: https://ckon.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/put-mysql-functions-back-into-php-7/

Comment: @phansen All I can say is that's an incredibly bad idea. Migrate to PDO or mysqli. Jumping through hoops to put back deprecated functionality is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 18):

PHP 7 has removed mysql_* completely.

You need to use PDO or mysqli. Wordpress seems not to support this.

Comment: the `mysql_*` were removed completely in PHP 7 not only the support of them, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I didn't find this answer very helpful.  Is PDO or mysqli better for a Wordpress site?  What needs to be done to upgrade?

Comment: that's crazy that they don't (still don't in '18) - this should really be sorted by them

Answer (score 9):

`mysql_*` functions got deleted in PHP 7.0 update your code to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Also take a look at prepared statements if you are handling user input. To reduce the chance of [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

An example of mysqli connection string:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
?>
```

An example of pdo connection string:

```
<?php
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
?>
```

*Note:*

That mysqli example handles a connection error

Comment: How can I do that? A quick google doesn't reveal some sort of setting to change it.

Comment: no it mysqli is just like `mysql_*` functions just code I'll add an example

Comment: also read the manuals it explains everything you need to know.

Comment: wp-db.php has some interesting variables related to mysqli.

Comment: why the downvote really like to know so I can improve the answers I give in the future :)

Comment: Is PDO or mysqli better for a Wordpress site? What actually needs to be done to upgrade?

Comment: @Keith In general PDO is more recommended as it has a better Integration of Prepared Statements and is database engine neutral. What I understand the only thing needed to use one or the other is the upgrade to PHP version 7+ . And of course update the code where required. Now I don't have much experience with WordPress but from what I know WordPress should keep itself up-to-date. If you are not sure if it is check it google for PHP version check WordPress, or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the Wordpress still using the Mysql extension that was removed in PHP7.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php

The Mysqli and PDO extensions were kept. This is the reason your other websites are working.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is caused by php 7.1.0-dev.

I built another one with the same configuration version 7.0.0 and the issue was resolved.

This has nothing to do with WordPress since it will automatically try to use MySQLi when MySQL is not found. At least in WP 4.4.

Comment: ... and if you're not using the latest version of WordPress, you should — because of security issues on previous versions. There _is_ a reason why WordPress is constantly being upgraded :-)

Answer (score -2):

On Ubuntu, I fixed this error by running

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

And then restarting my server (caddy, but you might be using apache or nginx).

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083448/3006854)