# How to restart php-fpm inside a docker container?

Tags: php, docker

I'm using docker and my container is build over php:5.6-fpm image from [php official repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).
Is it somehow possible to restart/reload php-fpm from inside a container?

Answer (score 114):

`php-fpm` is a process manager which supports the USER2 signal, which is used to reload the config file.

From inside the container:

```
kill -USR2 1
```

Outside:

```
docker exec -it <mycontainer> kill -USR2 1
```

Complete example:

```
docker run -d --name test123 php:7.1-fpm-alpine
docker exec -it test123 ps aux
docker exec -it test123 kill -USR2 1
docker exec -it test123 ps aux
```

Comment: Works great when I'm in the container. But calling if from outside errors: `rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"kill\": executable file not found in $PATH"` 
Any idea why?

Comment: @panepeter If you provide the way you run it I could provide more advice but the error message says it can't find the kill command in the path. Depending on your image you need to run it in certain ways, e.g. /bin/sh -c kill -USR2 1 ... That's my best guess without further info.

Comment: Thanks @Encrico, you were right! `/bin/bash -c kill -USR2 1` did the trick!

Comment: I had to use `kill -s USR2 1`.

Comment: What does 1 mean? How does know which process it kills?

Comment: @Gherman `1` is the process ID (PID). As its the only process started in that image it will be always 1.

Comment: For me PID 1 is not always correct (especially after killing it once). What helps is `pkill -o -USR2 php-fpm`, because the option `-o` searches for the oldest process (the master) and kills it.

Comment: @olidem If you kill PID 1 in any way that actually kills the process (eg. the famous `kill -9`), a new process will be spawned with a new PID. This solution only works repeatedly if you use the `-USR2` flag since it doesn't actually kill the process, it just tells it to reload the config (similar to a restart as the original question asked for).

Comment: Interestingly enough, locally I could send SIGHUP to my php-fpm master process to restart it, but when working with php-fpm in docker I needed to use the USR2 signal as described in this answer for it to work.

Comment: Handy one-liner: `pgrep php-fpm | xargs kill -USR2`

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to go inside the container

on your host

`ps -ef|grep fpm  // find master pid
kill -USR2 <master_pid>`

Comment: You might also need to install the procps package (Ubuntu/Debian image) which contains the ps util

Comment: PIDPHPFPM=$(ps -ef | grep fpm | grep master | awk '{print $2}') && kill -USR2 $PIDPHPFPM

Answer (score 0):

```
docker container kill --signal USR2 php_container_name
```

Details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_kill/

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

If the command fpm restart fails run this inside the Docker container -> www#:

```
root@...:/var/www# **ps -ef|grep fpm**  
www-data   160     1  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www  
www-data   161     1  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www  
root      1111   170  0 10:04 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto fpm  

root@...:/var/www# **kill -USR2 170**  

root@...:/home/user/Docker# **docker-compose stop**  
Stopping docker_nginx_1  ... done  
Stopping docker_oracle_1 ... done  

root@...:/home/user/Docker# **docker-compose up -d**  
Starting docker_oracle_1 ... done  
Starting docker_nginx_1  ... done  

root@...:/home/user/Docker# **docker-compose exec oracle bash**

root@...:/var/www# **/etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm restart**  
 * Restarting PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager php-fpm7.2                                          **[ OK ]**
```

Answer (score -4):

You can also just restart the container..

```
sudo docker restart <container>
```

Comment: e.g. `cd /apps/laradock && docker-compose restart nginx`