# Unable to restart php-fpm in alpine linux nginx docker image

Tags: php, docker, nginx, alpine-linux

I am trying to get php to work on the official nginx alpine linux docker image `nginx:alpine`. At the entrypoint of the container, I am running a script that does something like:

`rc-service -v php-fpm7 restart && nginx-debug -g "daemon off;"`

but alpine linux keeps on showing

> WARNING: php-fpm7 is already starting

I have also tried executing inside the container `rc-service -v php-fpm7 stop` and then `rc-service -v php-fpm7 start`, but I get pretty much the same error:

> ERROR: php-fpm7 stopped by something else
>   WARNING: php-fpm7 is already starting

after doing this a random number of times, I get:

```
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 273: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/tasks: Read-only file system
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
 * ERROR: networking failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start php-fpm7 as networking would not start
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: would this help somehow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806188/how-to-restart-php-fpm-inside-a-docker-container

Comment: Use php:7.1-fpm-alpine and install manually nginx.

Comment: @Muhammad thanks but not really, this is specific to alpine linux. 
Pyton I am gonna give it try

Comment: @zakariaamine oops overlooked sorry

Comment: @Pyton still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: This issue took me weeks to look, somehow found out that this issue happen at alpine:3.8, but it working fine at alpine:3.7. Please update me if this working for ya.

Comment: thanks for the update. After multiple attempts, I decided to use debian based image, I will try again and let you know

Comment: https://github.com/k2levin/php-laravel

I finally fixed mine issue in alpine, please give it a star if my script helping you..

Comment: I am getting the same error. Was this ever fixed?

Comment: no it did not, at least for me.