# phpMyAdmin - Error : (The mysqli extension is missing) after upgrading php 5.6 to php 7

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php-7

I have a problem with phpmyadmin on ubuntu 16.04 after upgrading php 5.6 to php 7 by this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

after this command :

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

phpMyadmin has error :

The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

But it does not have error on php5.

I want use phpMyadmin on php7.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your apt-get install doesn't seem to install mysqli

Comment: [This might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424982/how-to-enable-mysqli-extension-in-php-7)

Comment: You helped me to solve my problem.Thank you @apokryfos

Comment: You helped me to solve my problem.Thank you @AlphaDelta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to install php7 , then install php5.

1. Completely remove your php and phpmyadmin : 

   `sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin
   sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
   sudo service apache2 restart
   sudo apt-get purge php.*
   sudo service apache2 restart`
2. Install php7 and php7.0-mysql and ... : https://askubuntu.com/a/705893/424146
3. Install phpmyadmin (on php7) : [install phpmyadmin with lamp stack on ubuntu 16.04](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-phpmyadmin-with-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/)
4. Run these commands again to install php5.6 beside your php7:

Install php5.6 beside php7  : (I got help from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Switch PHP version:

From php5.6 to php7.0 :

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

From php7.0 to php5.6 :

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to do following steps.

```
php --version
```

Check your php version and run following command.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql
```

In my case my version of php is 5.6, you may have different. Replace your version and hit enter.

After installing just run

> sudo service apache2 restart

Hope it will help

Comment: it works well. my php verstion was php7.2. so I used this: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql`

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall or Reconfigure PHPMyAdmin.  The following worked for me:

dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Windows PC

Try to check to check your httpd-xampp config file.

Make sure the Make sure the Php-Module conform with your current php version.

example here: IfModule php5_module

Based on your migration you are using php7, so edit all the php5_module tag in your config file to php7_module and restart the apache server.