# MySQL functions not available in "php:7.1" docker image

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using the "php:7.1" docker image to setup the test environment for a new project. I get errors to while trying to use the

```
$db = new mysqli(...);
```

functions to acquire a DB connection.

I tried to use the docker image in interactive mode to find the necessary setup steps manually:

```
docker run -i -t php:7.1 /bin/bash
```

I run the following steps I found on the net to prepare the "mysqli" functions:

```
# update image
apt-get update
# install vim for local editing
apt-get install vim
```

I tried to install mysql from the following post: [How to enable MySQLi extension in php 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424982/how-to-enable-mysqli-extension-in-php-7/35425511)

```
apt-get install php-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-mysql
```

I tried to activate the extension only but does not work because the extenstion does not exists:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Error:

```
php info.php |grep mysql
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_mysqli.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d' '--disable-cgi' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--with-curl' '--with-libedit' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib'
mysqlnd
mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b396954eeb2d1d9ed7902b8bae237b287f21ad9e $
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
mysqlnd statistics =>
```

I have not an idea what I can do to get the extension installed and enabled.

Comment: Try building your docker file using https://phpdocker.io/ -- it has a generator that allows you to tick the features you want, and get a working docker file out at the end. Really easy and avoids a lot of hassle.

Comment: dll is a windows stuff. for linux you need so

Comment: I used .so as extension. This was a copy/paste from the web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're doing it wrong. First thing MySQL extension, the old one, gets deprecated in PHP 7+. It doesn't exists on Debian based distros either. So what you need to do is create a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
FROM php:7.1
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

And run the commands assuming you're in the directory where the `Dockerfile` lives :

```
docker build -t <some_tag> .
docker run -it <some_tag> bash
```

You will get into the prompt of your container and you can run then `php -v` the output should be something like:

```
# php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
mysqli ===> MySQLi has been installed
mysqlnd ===> MySQLnd has been installed
...
```