# configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>

Tags: php, pdo, php-extension, mysqlnd

I've installed the php7 on my redhat server,while i want to use the mysql extension.I cd the php7 source ext dir,and configured many times but all result that "configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's ".It's awfal!

1.I had the openssl there.

```
[root@xx mysqlnd]# rpm -qa|grep -i openssl
pyOpenSSL-0.10-2.el6.x86_64
openssl-1.0.0-20.el6.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.0-20.el6.x86_64
libcurl-openssl-7.33.0-2.2.x86_64
libcurl-openssl-devel-7.33.0-2.2.x86_64
```

2. I had tried amost all of the methods such as "ln the lib" or "Instead of --with-openssl-dir=/usr/include/openssl just use --with-openssl" the first 3 pages of results by google search,but all makes no help.

so,what can i do if i want use the mysql driver for php ?

Comment: Can this be related to the fact the the `mysql_*` was removed from PHP 7?  ([see this answer for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289954/compiled-php-7-missing-mysql-extension-in-wordpress)).  You need `mysqli`.  You did not say which extension you're using so i'm guessing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force remove the old php and add mysqlnd extension at the begining of reinstall by configure include options '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-mysqlnd'. Now,it works well.
But,it's not a good idea...

Comment: If it's not a good idea, either don't recommend it, or explain why it is not a good idea :)