# Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h> when installing mysqlnd on PHP 7.0.13

Tags: php, c, pdo, php-7, mysqlnd

I'm getting the following error when trying to install mysqlnd extension on PHP 7.0.13.

My `openssl` files are located on `/usr/include/openssl/` according to `locate evp.h`.

Already tried these:

- `--with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl/`
- `--with-openssl-dir=/usr/include/openssl/`
- Installing `libssl-dev`
- https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/138
- [configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604936/configure-error-cannot-find-openssls-evp-h)

Still getting the same error.

```
./configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13
checking for PHP includes... -I/root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13/include/php -I/root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13/include/php/main -I/root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13/include/php/TSRM -I/root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13/include/php/Zend -I/root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13/include/php/ext -I/root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /root/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.13/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable mysqlnd... yes, shared
checking whether to disable compressed protocol support in mysqlnd... yes
checking for the location of libz... no
checking for DSA_get_default_method in -lssl... no
checking for X509_free in -lcrypto... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
```

**UPDATE**

Found [an entry](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72363&edit=3) on bugs.php.net describing a problem with `mysqlnd`'s `configure` file, maybe this could be related.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having this (or similar) problem here are some of my findings installing PHP 7.1 on Ubuntu 17.04 using [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew).

I tried to install php-7.1 using phpbrew as follows:

```
phpbrew install 7.1 +default
```

This fails reporting that is unable to find Openssl library, some github issues and forums suggest using the following instead:

```
phpbrew install 7.1 +default +mysql +openssl=/usr/local/openssl/
```

Which also fails with the exact same error message as the original question:

> Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>

In fact the file can be found in /usr/local/openssl making the situation even more strange.

I Finally found solution as suggested in a phpbrew issue [111](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/111#issuecomment-173811458):

```
 phpbrew install 7.1 +default +openssl=shared -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/include/openssl
```

Notice that +openssl now says **shared** and --with-openssl-dir is used to indicate the same path as before **/usr/include/openssl**

Comment: It worked for me with a old version of PHP and OpenSSL compiled in a special directory  like `phpbrew install --old 5.3.7 +default +openssl=shared -- --with-openssl-dir=/opt/OpenSSL/openssl-1.0.1u`