# Why am I getting mysql extension error when I try to run a cron job?

Tags: php, php-extension

I just simply want to trigger a php script that coded as cron job.
When I tried to trigger it from Terminal as follows, I keep getting  this error.

I've been searching for a while about this error. But still, I couldn't get the reason why ...

Any opinions ? I'm stucked.

```
/usr/bin/php /Users/somethingunusual/IdeaProjects/local/secure/cron/payment/listing/return/job.cron.php 

logFor=LOCAL_DB errorMessage=[Error message: extension mysql is not compiled into PHP]
 code=-4 type=MDB2_Error level=1024 mode=1 query=SET NAMES LATIN5
logFor=LOCAL_DB errorMessage=[Error message: extension mysql is not compiled into PHP]
 code=-4 type=MDB2_Error level=1024 mode=1 query=SET NAMES LATIN5
logFor=LOCAL_DB errorMessage=[Error message: extension mysql is not compiled into PHP]
 code=-4 type=MDB2_Error level=1024 mode=1 query=SET NAMES LATIN5
logFor=LOCAL_DB errorMessage=[Error message: extension mysql is not compiled into PHP]
 code=-4 type=MDB2_Error level=1024 mode=1 query=SELECT paramValue FROM xx.sysparameters WHERE paramId = 'LISTING'
logFor=LOCAL_DB errorMessage=[Error message: extension mysql is not compiled into PHP]
 code=-4 type=MDB2_Error level=1024 mode=1 query=SELECT * xx.tmp_list WHERE RETURNED IN('0', '3') LIMIT 100
logFor=LOCAL_DB errorMessage=[Error message: extension mysql is not compiled into PHP]
 code=-4 type=MDB2_Error level=1024 mode=1 query=UPDATE xx.tmp_list SET RETURNED = '2' WHERE ID IN()
logFor=LOCAL_DB errorMessage=[Error message: extension mysql is not compiled into PHP]
 code=-4 type=MDB2_Error level=1024 mode=1 query=SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, RETURNED FROM xx.tmp_list GROUP BY RETURNED
```

Comment: *Any opinions ?* - [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Hm.. I'm aware of this. The thing is, I'm responsible of a cron job at the office. It has many business details going between mysql and php parts that I dont want to be involved. I guess changing my php version to older versions might help in a short term

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have mysql extensions for PHP installed.

It is usually called 'php-mysql' or something similar, depending on the system/distribution you are using.

Comment: actually, I can observe the mysqli module when I search for php modules with "php -m" command. So.. I guess this is not the case.

Comment: I also have the related extension in php.ini file too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `mysql` extension in your `ext` directory of the server. However, Using `mysql` is deprecated in PHP and no longer supported in recent PHP variants. You can use `mysqli` instead.

> `mysql` extension is deprecated and no longer available from php v5.5.X anymore. Head over to [Official Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` extension. Before using it, make sure it's enabled in `php.ini` file. remove `;` prefix of `extension=mysqli.so` in php.ini and restart the server if not enabled.

Comment: I've reached out to the same information when I try to find out the reason why. But  unfortunately this didn't solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue recently.  I solved it by converting my code to connect to the database using PDO paradigm.  For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289954/compiled-php-7-missing-mysql-extension-in-wordpress